# First sendKeys is always ignored in a consecutive sendKeys

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a consecutive sendKeys opertions like blow:

```
 elem1.sendKeys("value1")
 elem2.sendKeys("value2")
 elem3.sendKeys("value3")
```

After swithing the ordering freely,I notice that the first sendKey will always be ignored,and I am using

```
 selenium 2.44.0
 ubuntu 14.04 64bit
 java 1.8
 groovy 2.3.7
 spock 1.0 for groovy 2.3
 chromeDriver for linux 64bit
```

and I did some googling,found some guys suggest to put some sleeping,but It may bury problem,so I want to know  what cause this problem?

**Update:add actual html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="GDXPHJADNP">
    <div class="GDXPHJADLP left">
      <input warning="Email is invalid,and it should looks like:jessi@xmial.com" id="identifier" title="email" pattern="EMAIL" class="GDXPHJADOP GDXPHJADMP description descriptionLight warning" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="GDXPHJADLP right">
      <input id="password" title="password" pattern="PASSWORD" class="GDXPHJADOP  GDXPHJADMP description descriptionLight" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="GDXPHJADNP">
    <div class="GDXPHJADLP left">
      <input id="name" title="your name" warning="Name must be 1~30 characters" class="GDXPHJADOP  GDXPHJADMP required description descriptionLight" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

By the way,I am using PageFactory(provided by selenium's java api).I think if some values can be set into some inputs by sendKey,it means page object has been initialized correctly,and all elements have been find out correctly,is this assumption right?

Comment: Please use  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML code snippet where you are facing the problem ?

Comment: @Subh,original html quite a lot,so I clearned it then paster here.And I find out any special here:three inputs:identifier,password,name.

Comment: Okay.. I don't know about PageFactory much. Try sending text only to the first element using `elem1.sendKeys("value1")` and let us know if it sends text to that or not.

Comment: sending test only to first element doesn't work,and I have done this: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);